# How can I fix my Bluetooth Settings?

Tags: bluetooth

I paired up my Galaxy S3 (running Android Kit-Kat) to my laptop running Ubuntu, and my phone seems to think that Ubuntu is a Bluetooth speaker. It works as a bluetooth speaker mind you, but I need to send my files to the computer, wirelessly, since my phone has a wobbly physical connection.

I know I could use an alternative like google drive or dropbox, but it'd be nice if the bluetooth worked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Install the blueman package. Blueman is a graphical configuration tool for Bluetooth. Install it from the Software Center or run the following in a terminal (without quotes):

'sudo apt-get install blueman'

After installing, run it with the command 'blueman' or by searching "blue" in the dash.